# Is this known alternating sum for Euler's constant?

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, sequences-and-series

This probably is known, but Wolfram Alpha doesn't recognize it
and couldn't find it in Mathworld (there is something close,
but using floor).

We have 
$\lim_{s \to 1} (\zeta(s)-1/(s-1)) = \gamma$

Also 
$F(s) = \zeta(s) = \frac{1}{1-2^{1-s}}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^s} $.

According to Maple 13:
$$\lim_{s \to 1} (F(s)-1/(s-1)) = \sum _{n=1}^{\infty }-{\frac { \left( -1 \right) ^{n-1}\ln  \left( n \right) }{n}} \left( \ln  \left( 2 \right)  \right) ^{-1}+1/2\,\ln \left( 2 \right) = \gamma \qquad (1) $$

> Is (1) known and/or trivial?

I believe all terms and partial sums except the first of the sum are transcendental.

> Intuitive explanation how (1) could be hypothetically rational?

---

> Reference request? Was this known to Euler?

Numerically (1) is correct to precision at least $500$ decimal digits.

Sage code:

```
nsu=1/2*mpmath.log(2)-mpmath.nsum(lambda n:  (-1)**(n-1)*mpmath.log(n)/n ,[1, mpmath.inf])/ mpmath.log(2);nsu
```

Comment: Surely, just as the infinite sum of rationals need not be rational, there's no reason to expect an infinite sum of transcendentals to be transcendental?  (Indeed, even a *finite* sum of transcendentals need not be transcendental!)

Answer (score 11):

Denote 
$$
f(s)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^s}=(1-2^{1-s})\zeta(s). 
$$
Expanding into series and using $\zeta(s)=\frac1{s-1}+\gamma+O((s-1))$ leads to
$$
f(s)=\log 2+(s-1) \left(\gamma  \log 2-\frac{\log
   ^22}{2}\right)+O\left((s-1)^2\right).
$$
Differentiating both sides gives
$$
f'(1)=
-\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }{\frac { \left( -1 \right) ^{n-1}\ln  \left( n \right) }{n}}= 
\gamma  \log 2-\frac{\log
   ^22}{2}.
$$

Comment: Thanks. How an infinite linear combination of logarithms and sqrt(2) can be rational?

Comment: Same way that the infinite linear combination
$$\frac{1}{e}+\frac{1}{e}+\frac{1}{2e}+\frac{1}{6e}+\frac{1}{24e}+\cdots$$ can be 1?

Comment: @JamesCranch linear combination of $e$ appears quite different to me from $\log{n}$.

Comment: Andrew, I fail to see which part of the question you answered. Maybe you answered "it is trivial" since you and Maple proved it. I just added "reference request" and "Was this known to Euler?".